# Remove multiple rows based on missing values in fewer rows - Cannot allocate vector of size

Tags: r

I have an R data frame with data from multiple subjects, each tested several times. To perform statistics on the set, there is a factor for subject ("id") and a row for each observation (around 40,000) with around 200 variables each.

```
allData <- data.frame(id       = rep(1:4, 3),
                      session  = rep(1:3, each = 4),
                      measure1 = sample(c(NA, 1:11)),
                      measure2 = sample(c(NA, 1:11)),
                      measure3 = sample(c(NA, 1:11)),
                      measure4 = sample(c(NA, 1:11)))
allData                      
#    id session measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4
# 1   1       1        3        7       10        6
# 2   2       1        4        4        9        9
# 3   3       1        6        6        7       10
# 4   4       1        1        5        2        3
# 5   1       2       NA       NA        5       11
# 6   2       2        7       10        6        5
# 7   3       2        9        8        4        2
# 8   4       2        2        9        1        7
# 9   1       3        5        1        3        8
# 10  2       3        8        3        8        1
# 11  3       3       11       11       11        4
# 12  4       3       10        2       NA       NA
```

I need to remove all rows with id 1 and 4, given that the "measureX" (X=1,..,4) column contains NA in one of the rows for the id 1 and 4.

A solution for this problem was suggested by flodel in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917524/5042101][1]  using the "plyr" package and the function ddply.

```
probeColumns = c('measure1','measure4')

library(plyr)
ddply(allData, "id",
      function(df)if(any(is.na(df[, probeColumns]))) NULL else df)
```

Problem.  My database includes around 40,000 rows and 200 columns.  An error appears when I try for a single column: C stack usage 10027284.

I am using R 3.1.3 in RStudio on Windows.  When a try for more columns RStudio close up automatically or R freezes.  Moreover, I do not have access to the administrator session in the computer.

Comment: What do you mean by id==(1,4) ? This isn't R syntax, so a verbal description would be useful

Comment: @rsoren - `id %in% c(1,4)` I think they mean.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what the problem is with `plyr` (though it might be a bug in the package). It is possible to do this using `apply`:

```
> allData[apply(allData, 1, function(x) !any(is.na(x[probeColumns]))), ]
   id session measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4
1   1       1        1        1        2        4
2   2       1        5        4        6        1
3   3       1        9        8       NA        3
4   4       1       11        7        7        5
5   1       2        8        5       11        2
6   2       2        6       NA        5        8
7   3       2       10       10        3       10
9   1       3        4        9        4        9
10  2       3        2        6        8        7
11  3       3        3        3        9        6
```

A bit of explanation - `apply(allData, c(1), function(x) !any(is.na(x[probeColumns])))` determines the indexes of rows that don't have `NA` in columns specified by `probeColumns` by going row by row and checking if any of the values in a row in `probeColums` are `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution a little bit clumsy maybe but here is the idea:

1. Find out where are located the `NA`s
2. then identify at which `id` they correspond
3. Last step remove all id elements that have at least
   (in at least one column) an `NA`.

   ```
   ind <- allData[apply(allData, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) == !0, 1 ]

   allData %>% filter(!id %in% ind)
     id session measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4
   1  1       1        1        6        1        8
   2  2       1       10        2        7        2
   3  1       2       11        7        5       11
   4  2       2        5        5        4        7
   5  1       3        4        8        9        5
   6  2       3        8       11        3        9
   ```